# Is it possible to add a network route to a Docker container running in a swarm?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm, openvpn

In our swarm, some containers will need to access external service via an OpenVPN connection.

Adhering to separation of responsibilities, we implement a client OpenVPN containers that will be responsible for the VPN layer. And we intend other containers to use it as a gateway when they need to reach a machine on the VPN.

### Example

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable vpn_net
# Start the gateway on this network
docker run --name openvpn -d --cap-add NET_ADMIN --network vpn_net openvpn-client
# deploy a swarm of containers
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml custom-stack
```

(With `docker-compose.yml` notably making `vpn-net` one of the networks available to the services that require VPN connectivity.)

---

Sadly, said containers are not able to ping IPs on the VPN (even though the `openvpn` container successfully ping them). And it seems we are not allowed to add routes to the containers running in the swarm:

```
$ route add -net 192.168.2.0/24 gw openvpn
SIOCADDRT: Operation not permitted
```

Is there any way to add such route to the containers in the swarm?

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this? I'm trying to hide containers behind openvpn, there's literally no guides for what I need out there.

Comment: looking for the same here